# How to send png images from iPhone to web service

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have been trying to send .png images from iPhone to web service. I have come so fas as converting the .png image into a byte[] array. I am clueless as to how to use soap or HTTP get/post to transfer the byte[] image to the web service.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sayeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use just an HTTP-POST, you can try the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library. it wraps the NSHTTPRequest into an easy-to-use container.
there is also an [example](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) how to submit files (your png).

Comment: I couldn't find the example you referred to

Sayeed

Comment: open the example page above and search for "Sending data".
you'll find an easy to understand example how to send a POST request with a file attached.